# https http in exchange 2003 iis(6.0)

Tags: windows-server-2003

hello guys i have setup ssl for my exchange server.

now i wanne made that its not possible to connect with outlook tot he exchange server using http

i only wanne make it possible over https

now both work http en https i wanne block http en allow https.

somebody any advice?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are referring to OWA (Outlook Web Access), [here's a guide](http://www.msexchange.org/tutorials/Securing-Exchange-Server-2003-Outlook-Web-Access-Chapter5.html) for Exchange Server 2003 to block HTTP access and redirect to HTTPS.